# put list of IP addresses into config file as text

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have config file for fail2ban where I try to put multiple IP addresses automaticly with script. But I am probably doing some mistake as the script is spamming `ignoreip = ip` in a loop till the fille is spammed with thousand of lines like this.

How to properly formate it or put into a file? My script is below:

```
#! /bin/bash
cat  $WHITELIST_IP | while read ip; do
    #echo -e $ip
sed '10d' /etc/fail2ban/jail_test.conf
sed -i "10i ignoreip = $ip" /etc/fail2ban/jail_test.conf
done
```

I understand I am sending sed in a loop thats why it is still repearing same line, but how to prevent it or do it better?

Comment: Why are you using `sed`? Is the `jail_test.conf` file already populated with entries? If not, why not try `echo "ignoreip = $ip" >> /etc/fail2ban/jail_test.conf` instead?

Comment: I need to put it on specific line because in other was F2B process will fail to start.

Answer (score 0):

From your case, I can assume that `/etc/fail2ban/jail_test.conf` is already populated with other entries as you said that file is spammed with thousand of lines like this.

Since, you are using a `while` loop, the command `sed '10d' /etc/fail2ban/jail_test.conf` actually echo the whole file after deleting 10th line at each loop. However, you are not using the option `-i` after `sed`, thus there will be no change in-place will be done in the file itself.

What I understand from your script that you want to delete 10th line in the file `/etc/fail2ban/jail_test.conf` and insert whitelist IPs from the file `$WHITELIST_IP` at 10th line in the file `/etc/fail2ban/jail_test.conf`.

If so, and you must want to use `while` loop, then:

```
#! /bin/bash

sed -i '10d' /etc/fail2ban/jail_test.conf

while read ip; do
    sed -i "10i ignoreip = $ip" /etc/fail2ban/jail_test.conf
done < $WHITELIST_IP
```

if you use `10d` and `10i` both together inside the loop, then it will delete the 10th line at each loop and only the one IP address at the last loop will be inserted at 10th line.

If you simply want to append IP address from `$WHITELIST_IP` to `/etc/fail2ban/jail_test.conf` file in the desired format, then:

`cat $WHITELIST_IP | xargs -n1 echo "ignoreip =" >> /etc/fail2ban/jail_test.conf`

Comment: The oneliner you posted does what my while loop does, add ignoreip = ip_address on line for every IP, which does not work in fail2ban configuration.

Also script you posted just delete line but sadly does not input anything on that line.